# in multithreaded programming does synchronization strip the benefits of concurrent executions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a dilemma regarding the use of multithreading in the application I am working on.  I have a workflow in which the state of the object changes, which presents no issues for single-threaded operation.  However, In order to improve the performance, I am planning to use multiple threads.

It is my understanding that since the state is going to be shared among the threads, every thread must acquire a lock on the state before execution, so doesn't this defeat the purpose of multithreading?  It seems like multiple threads won't produce any actual concurrency, so it wouldn't be any better than single threaded.

Is my analysis correct?  If I am misunderstanding then would someone please clarify the concept?

Comment: multithreading can help if you have many such objects.

Comment: or if the object can be split up into independent parts, and the parts advanced from stage to stage in parallel.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the situation. You will not gain understanding by relying on SO. You will have to study the subject, and study hard. Very, very hard. I suggest to purchase and study _Java Concurrency in Practice_, by Brian Goetz _et al._ There are other good books out there. Look for works by Goetz, Doug Lea, or Joshua Bloch. There are articles on IBM's Developerworks site, too. Be diligent in your studies. It takes a while. I've been studying concurrent programming for decades and still work at it. Learn about _happens-before_ in the memory model.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: concurrency is hard. Real concurrency, with multiple concurrent writers, is *really* hard.

What you need to determine is what your actual consistency guarantees need to be. Does every reader need to be able to see every write, guaranteed? Then you'll be forced into [*linearizing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) all the threads somehow (e.g. using locks) -- your next effort should be to ensure you do as much work as possible outside of the lock, to keep the lock held for the shortest possible time.

One way to keep the lock held for the shortest possible time is to use a [*lock-free algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm). Most lock-free algorithms are based on an atomic compare-and-set primitive, such as those provided by the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package. These can be very high-performance, but designing a successful lock-free algorithm can be subtle. One simple kind of lock-free algorithm is to just build a new (immutable) state object and then atomically make it the "live" state, retrying in a loop if a different state was made live by another writer in the interim. (This approach is good enough for many applications, but it's vulnerable to livelock if you have too many writers.)

If you can get by with a looser consistency guarantee, then many other optimizations are possible. For example, you can use thread-local caches so that each thread sees its own view of the data and can be writing in parallel. Then you need to deal with the consequences of data being stale or inconsistent. Most techniques in this vein strive for [*eventual consistency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency): writes may not be visible to all readers immediately, but they are guaranteed to be visible to all readers eventually.

This is an active area of research, and a complete answer could fill a book (really, several books!). If you're just getting started in this area, I'd recommend you read [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](http://jcip.net) by Goetz et al, as it provides a good introduction to the subject and lots of practical advice about how to successfully build concurrent systems.

Comment: Great points with lock-free algorithms and eventual consistency.

Comment: Google yields about 17.600 results for "concurrency is hard", while "concurrency is simple" gives about 45.700 results. Indeed, concurrency is simple when considered as a "token game". Another approach to cope with complexity is functional programming. Functional programs are easy to parallelise. One need not to use functional language: use Java, but avoid mutable variables. Let variables be assigned once, at the moment of declaration. As a result, the program now looks like a huge expression, and one can easily see parallel branches of that expression, which can be computed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of the limits of multithreading and concurrency are correct.  Since the state must be acquired and controlled by threads in order for them to perform work (and waiting when not working), you are essentially splitting the work of a single thread among multiple threads.

The best way to fix this is to adjust your program design to limit the size of the `critical section`.  As we learned in my operating systems course with process synchronization,

> only one critical section must be executing at any given time

The specific term **critical section** may not directly apply to Java concurrency, but it still illustrates the concept.

What does it mean to limit this **critical section**?  For example, let's say you have a program managing a single bank account (unrealistic, but illustrates my point).  If a lock on the account must be acquired by a thread for the balance to be updated, the basic option would be to have a single thread working on updating the balance at all times **(without concurrency).  The critical section would be the entire program**.  However, let's say there was also other logic to be executed, such as alerting other banks of the balance update.  You could require the lock on the bank account state only while updating the balance, and not when alerting other banks, **decreasing the size of critical section and allowing other threads to perform work** by alerting other banks while one thread is updating the balance.

Please comment if this was unclear.  Your seem to already understand the constraints of concurrency, but hopefully this will reveal possible steps towards implementing concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Your need is not totally clear but you guess well the limitations that multi threading may have. 
Running parallel threads have a sense if some "relatively autonomous" tasks can be  concurrently performed by distinct threads or group of threads.

If your scenario looks like : you start 5 threads and finally only a single thread is active while the others are waiting for a locking resource, using multithreading makes no sense and could even introduce an overhead because of cpu context switches.

I think that in your use case, the multithreading could be used for :

- tasks that don't change the state
- performing a task that changes the state if the task may be divided in multiple processing with a minimal set of instructions that may do profitable the multithreading use.

Answer (score 1):

> It is my understanding that since the state is going to be shared among the threads, every thread must acquire a lock on the state before execution, so doesn't this defeat the purpose of multithreading?

The short answer is "it depends".  It is rare that you have a multithreaded application that has no shared data.  So sharing data, even if it needs a full lock, doesn't necessarily defeat the performance improvements when making a single threaded application be multi-threaded.

The big question is what the frequency that the state needs to be updated by each thread.  If the threads read in the state, do their concurrent processing which takes time, and then alter the state at the end then you may see performance gains.  On the other hand, if every step in the processing needs to somehow be coordinated between threads then they may all spend them time contending for the state object.  Reducing this dependence on shared state will then improve your multi-threaded performance.

There are also more efficient ways to update a state variable which can avoid locks.  Something like the following pattern is used a lot:

```
 private AtomicReference<State> sharedState;
 ...
 // inside a thread processing loop
 // do the processing job
 while (true) {
   State existingState = sharedState.get();
    // create a new state object from the existing and our processing
    State newState = updateState(state);
    // if the application state hasn't changed, then update it
    if (sharedState.compareAndSet(existingState, newState)) {
        break;
    }
    // otherwise we need to get the new existing state and try again
 }
```

One way to handle state changes is to have a coordinating thread.  It is the only thread which reads from the state and generates jobs.  As jobs finish they put updates to the state on a `BlockingQueue` which is then read by the coordinating thread which updates the state in turn.  Then the processing threads don't have to all be contending for access to the shared state.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine it this way :

1. Synchronization is blocking
2. Concurrency is parallelization

You don't have to use synchronization. You can use an Atomic reference object  as a wrapper for your shared mutable state.

You can also use stamped locks which improves concurrency by allowing for optimistic reads. You may also use Accumulators to write concurrent code. These features are part of Java 8.

Another way to prevent synchronization is to use immutable objects which can be shared and published freely and need no synchronization. I should add that you should use immutable objects anyway regardless of concurrency for that makes your state space of the object easier to reason about